# How to inject a Resource from classpath in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject a file from `src/main/resources` like this:

```
@Value("classpath:myfile.txt")
private Resource res;
```

When I run this from eclipse it works fine.
But from a standalone folder, the file is not found:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [myfile.txt] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/D:/myapp/myapp-1.0.0.jar!/myfile.txt
    at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:212) ~[spring-core-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
```

How can I tell spring that the file to be injected is actually in the root of the jar, not an absolute path?

Same result if I try to load it programmatically.

`res = new ClassPathResource("myfile.txt");`

Comment: Maybe you need to add resources to your jars classpath in MANIFEST file? The reason why it works in Eclipse is because Eclipse has its own classpath file which probably has the folder mapped in it.

Comment: Well I don't have to necessairly inject it from `src/main/resources` path in the compiled jar. It is already placed in the root, and from there it should be injected.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it'll work, but you can try it like this if your file is present in the same folder as jar.. `@Value(value = "classpath:"+"../"+"myfile.txt")` , but it's a hardcoded way which will conflict when run from eclipse

Comment: The file is not in the same folder, but INSIDE the compiled jar in the root of the jar!

Answer (score 1):

You said this works in eclipse:

```
@Value("classpath:myfile.txt")
private Resource res;
```

Now try this in eclipse (notice the `*`), if it works, standalone should be ok:

```
@Value("classpath*:myfile.txt")
private Resource res;
```

When deploying outside eclipse, make sure `myfile.txt` is on the classpath; the best location is in the root directory where Java class file packages are located (`com`, `org`)

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the injection itself did work, BUT I accessed the file using `res.getFile()` which threw the NPE.

When just retrieving the URL and fetching the file explicit with `File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(res.getURL().getFile());` it worked as expected.

Though I'm not sure wether this is a bug or works as expected.